# Then the entry in row 1, column 2 of B equals____????

Tags: linear-algebra

For $α ∈ R$, let $q(x_1, x_2) =x_1^2 + 2αx_1x_2  + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2$ for $(x_1,x_2) \in R^2$

(a) Take $α = \frac14$ and let B be the symmetric matrix of q with respect to the basis{${(1, 0),(1, 1)} $}of $R^2$. Then the entry in row $1$, column $2$ of B equals____????

my attempst : $q = \begin{bmatrix} 1& \frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

now the entries in row 1  is  $1$ and $\frac 14$ and column is $\frac 14$ and $\frac{1}{2}$

Is its corrects ??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respect to the standard basis

$$q=x^TAx$$

with

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1& \frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$$

let $M = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ the matrix for the change of basis $x=My$ then we have

$$q=x^TAx=(My)^TAMy=y^TM^TAMy$$

Comment: q=$ y^T \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 1& \frac{1}{4}\\\frac{1}{4}&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}y=y^T\begin{bmatrix}1&\frac{5}{4}\\\frac{5}{4}&\frac{3}{4}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix}y=y^T\begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{5}{4}\\\frac{5}{4}&2\end{bmatrix}y$...now  my question is that what  is  y ???

Comment: @Stupid y is the representation of x in the new basis, for example to $y=(0,1)$ corresponds $x=My=(1,1)$

Comment: +1 Hints ,,@ gimusi   what is the answer ??? as  i got entries in row 1  is  $1$ and $\frac 14$ and column is $\frac 14$ and $\frac{1}{2}$   is  its corrects??

Comment: @Henry Matrix B is $\begin{bmatrix} 1&\frac{5}{4}\\\frac{5}{4}&2\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: thanks a lots @gimusi

Comment: @Henry You are welcome! I see now that user396850 aka "Stupid" has gone away! I'm sorry for that, he was really funny!

Comment: @stupid I thought you was deleted as user396850!

Comment: @stupid Why heve you been deleted?

Comment: @stupid Anyway I suppose that call for an answer in the comment, even if made in good-faith, as in your case is not a allowed behaviour here. I'll ask for a clarification on that in order to avoid to you further deletion for abusive behaviour!

Comment: @stupid Try to take into account suggestions by moderators, they try to help us to use MSE properly. If you ask all the answer for which you need help in good.faith and properly you'll obtain support from the community. Don't use that as an homework machine, show your work and ask for doubs or clarifications. That's all. Bye