# what is signature of q?

Tags: linear-algebra

For $α ∈ R$, let $q(x_1, x_2) =x_1^2 + 2αx_1x_2  + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2$ for $(x_1,x_2) \in R^2$

b) find all values of $\alpha$ for which the signature of  q is  1.

my attempts : as  i know that

signature (s) =total number of positive entries - total no of negative entries

=$ p -(r-p) = 2p-r$ where  r is the rank of matrix

$q = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\1&\frac{1}{2}\end{bmatrix}$

now by elementray operation

$q = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$

here  $s = 2.1 -1$ where$ r= 1,p =1 $

therefore  signature(s) of $ q =1 $for $\alpha =1$

is  my answer  is correct or not ?????

Comment: What “elementary operation” produces $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}$ from $\tiny{\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1/2\end{bmatrix}}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let consider the associated matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1& \alpha\\\alpha&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$$

by [Sylvester criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion) note that

- $\det(1)=1$
- $\det A=\frac12-\alpha^2\implies \det A>0 \iff-\frac{\sqrt 2}2<\alpha<\frac{\sqrt 2}2$

Comment: thanks  a  lots  @Gimusi,,,pliz  help me  this question  also 
    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741287/then-the-entry-in-row-1-column-2-of-b-equals